# Не могу понять как сверстать блок с текстом со скроллом средствами html, css,js или jQuery?

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery, вёрстка

Начал изучать front-end. Основы изучил, начал брать разные макеты для тренировки с бирж. В одном из таких попался такой блок.[[image: 1]]

Суть: текст должен скролиться вниз по нажатию "Читать далее" Скроллбар должен быть там где выделено красным овалом и двигаться вниз вдоль белого блока. У меня получилось только сделать справа как видно на картинке. В какую сторону копать и как это реализовать?

```css
.profile-right {
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  border-left: 1px solid #E5E5E5;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 57px 69px 57px 60px;
  position: relative; }
  .profile-right:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 2px;
    height: 270px;
    background-color: #537FB3; }
  .profile-right__bg {
    position: absolute;
    width: 589px;
    height: 143px;
    bottom: 0;
    right: -25px; }
  .profile-right__text {
    overflow: auto;
    width: 650px;
    max-height: 353px;
    font-family: Montserrat;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 25px;
    /* or 156% */
    letter-spacing: 0.065em;
    color: #10406B; }
    .profile-right__text p {
      padding: 0 0 20px 0; }
  .profile-right__readmore {
    padding: 32px 0 0 0; }
```

```html
<div class="mainblock-profile__content profile-right">
                <div class="profile-right__bg ibg"><img src="img/backgrounds/bg2.png" alt=""></div>
                <div class="profile-right__text">
                  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
                  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
                  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
                  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
                </div>
                <a href="" class="profile-right__readmore items-readmore">
                  <div class="items-readmore__circle"><img src="img/icons/arrow.svg" alt=""></div>
                  <div class="items-readmore__next"><span>Читать далее</span></div>
                </a>
              </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Немного изменил Ваш код и сделал что-то такое (код ниже).

1. Для того чтобы сделать скроллбар слева, необходимо воспользоваться интересным трюком с помощью свойства `direction`. У родителя указываем направление `rtl` (right to left) а у всех `p` указываем `ltr`(left to right) тем самым текст возвращается в исходное положение, но расположение скроллбара становится в левой части.
2. webkit-scrollbar и прочие псевдоэлементы изменяют отображение скролбара (для мозилы и т.д. используйте -moz...
3. Далее простой скрипт jquery который считывает текущее расположение конца новости (блок `next`) и с помощью анимации делает скролл к нему.

```js
var $link = $('.autoscroll');
var duration = 800;

$link.click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var $elem = $(this.getAttribute('href'));
  $('.profile-right__text').animate({
      scrollTop: $elem.offset().top
  }, duration);
});
```

```css
.profile-right__text {
  direction: rtl;
  height: 160px;
  overflow:auto;
}

.profile-right__item {
  direction: ltr;
}

.profile-right__text::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 5px;
}
.profile-right__text::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background-color: #537FB3;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="mainblock-profile__content profile-right">
    <div class="profile-right__text">
    <p class="profile-right__item">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
    <p class="profile-right__item">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
    <p class="profile-right__item">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
    <p class="profile-right__item">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
    <div id="next"></div>
    </div>
    <a href="#next" class="autoscroll">Читать далее</a>
 </div>
```